# matplotlib fontsize seems wrong in pdf?

Tags: python, matplotlib, gnuplot

I am trying to create a plot for a journal. I know the column width is 164mm for full width and font size is 10. If I use gnuplot the font size matches and the plot looks good - i.e. matches the surrounding font size of the latex document.

I tried changing dpi as well as switching to tex - but neither had the desired effect of changing the font size. Introducing a factor ~1.5 for the figure size helps, but that is rather unsatisfying.

```
x=164/25.4*.5
set term pdf size x,x*0.75 font "TeX Gyre Termes,10"
set out 'fig_setup.gpl.pdf'
set xlabel 'x'
set ylabel 'y'
plot x
```

If I try to do the same with matplotlib the fontsize is to large:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig_width = 164.4 / 25.4  # 164.4 mm in inches
fs = 10
params = {
    "axes.labelsize": fs,
    "font.size": fs,
    "legend.fontsize": fs,
    "axes.titlesize": fs,
    "xtick.labelsize": fs,
    "ytick.labelsize": fs,
    "font.family": "serif",
    "font.serif": "TeX Gyre Termes",
}
plt.rcParams.update(params)

width = 0.5 * fig_width
height = 0.75 * width
plt.figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=72) # dpi without effect?
plt.plot([-10, 10], [-10, 10], label="x")
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.savefig("fig_setup.plt.pdf", dpi=600) # dpi does not change result
```

I would expect that both plots look roughly the same -

Gnuplot output:

[image: gnuplot]

Matplotlib output:

[image: matplotlib]

(Converted to png with: `convert -density $f.pdf $f.png`)

Comment: So, as I understand it is not a question about gnuplot but matplotlib? Then the gnuplot tag should be removed.

Comment: I think your width and height are wrong. In Matplotlib `figsize` refers to the entire figure, not the size of the axes.